# Difference between datepickers except sundays in infopath

Tags: infopath-2007

How to get the no of days between two date picker controls in info path except sundays?

If It is possible let me know.

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0):

Using custom code you can do it easily. In this case I'm calculating the number of days (except Sundays) between a given date and today's date.

```
var navigator = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
string startDate = navigator.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:date_start", NamespaceManager).Value;
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

int count = 0;

while (startDateTime > today)
{
    today = today.AddDays(1);

    if (today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps